# Why does Runtime.exec(String) work for some but not all commands?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

When I try to run `Runtime.exec(String)`, certain commands work, while other commands are executed but fail or do different things than in my terminal. Here is a self-contained test case that demonstrates the effect:

```
public class ExecTest {
  static void exec(String cmd) throws Exception {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    int i;
    while( (i=p.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
      System.out.write(i);
    }
    while( (i=p.getErrorStream().read()) != -1) {
      System.err.write(i);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.print("Runtime.exec: ");
    String cmd = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    exec(cmd);
  }
}
```

The example works great if I replace the command with `echo hello world`, but for other commands -- especially those involving filenames with spaces like here -- I get errors even though the command is clearly being executed:

```
myshell$ javac ExecTest.java && java ExecTest
Runtime.exec: ls -l 'My File.txt'
ls: cannot access 'My: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access File.txt': No such file or directory
```

meanwhile, copy-pasting to my shell:

```
myshell$ ls -l 'My File.txt'
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 4 Aug  2 11:44 My File.txt
```

Why is there a difference? When does it work and when does it fail? How do I make it work for all commands?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

#### Why do some commands fail?

This happens because the command passed to `Runtime.exec(String)` is not executed in a shell. The shell performs a lot of common support services for programs, and when the shell is not around to do them, the command will fail.

#### When do commands fail?

A command will fail whenever it depends on a shell features. The shell does a lot of common, useful things we don't normally think about:

1. **The shell splits correctly on quotes and spaces**

   This makes sure the filename in `"My File.txt"` remains a single argument.

   `Runtime.exec(String)` naively splits on spaces and would pass this as two separate filenames. This obviously fails.
2. **The shell expands globs/wildcards**

   When you run `ls *.doc`, the shell rewrites it into `ls letter.doc notes.doc`.

   `Runtime.exec(String)` doesn't, it just passes them as arguments.

   `ls` has no idea what `*` is, so the command fails.
3. **The shell manages pipes and redirections.**

   When you run `ls mydir > output.txt`, the shell opens "output.txt" for command output and removes it from the command line, giving `ls mydir`.

   `Runtime.exec(String)` doesn't. It just passes them as arguments.

   `ls` has no idea what `>` means, so the command fails.
4. **The shell expands variables and commands**

   When you run `ls "$HOME"` or `ls "$(pwd)"`, the shell rewrites it into `ls /home/myuser`.

   `Runtime.exec(String)` doesn't, it just passes them as arguments.

   `ls` has no idea what `$` means, so the command fails.

#### What can you do instead?

There are two ways to execute arbitrarily complex commands:

**Simple and sloppy:** delegate to a shell.

You can just use `Runtime.exec(String[])` (note the array parameter) and pass your command directly to a shell that can do all the heavy lifting:

```
// Simple, sloppy fix. May have security and robustness implications
String myFile = "some filename.txt";
String myCommand = "cp -R '" + myFile + "' $HOME 2> errorlog";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", myCommand });
```

**Secure and robust:** take on the responsibilities of the shell.

This is not a fix that can be mechanically applied, but requires an understanding the Unix execution model, what shells do, and how you can do the same. However, you can get a solid, secure and robust solution by taking the shell out of the picture. This is facilitated by `ProcessBuilder`.

The command from the previous example that requires someone to handle 1. quotes, 2. variables, and 3. redirections, can be written as:

```
String myFile = "some filename.txt";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "cp", "-R", myFile,        // We handle word splitting
       System.getenv("HOME")); // We handle variables
builder.redirectError(         // We set up redirections
    ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to(new File("errorlog")));
builder.start();
```

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { System.getenv("SHELL"), "-c", myCommand });

Comment: Prefer explicitly specifying a shell that you know can understand the command. Your program should not stop working just because a user picks `fish` or `pwsh` as their login shell.

Comment: It seems like the "simple and sloppy" approach (which I think is adequate for what I am doing) only handles one command at a time. How can a sequence of commands be handled?

Comment: Same way as in as shell: separating with `;` or `&&` or linefeeds