# Whitespace in bash path with java

Tags: java, bash, command-line-interface, whitespace

So, I try to export file variable:

```java
String somePath = "/Users/me/File with whitespaces.json";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

runtime.exec(String.format("$MY_FILEPATH=\"%s\"", somePath));
```

And I get some exception on this line:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "$MY_FILEPATH=/Users/me/File": error=2, No such file or directory
```

P.S.
If I try "prepend space in file name with ", I get:

```java
String somePath = "/Users/me/File\ with\ whitespaces.json";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

runtime.exec(String.format("open %s", somePath));
```

And I also get some exception on this line:

```
The files /Users/me/File\, with\, whitespaces.json do not exist.
```

P.P.S
If I wrap path in "", I also get exception like above

Comment: prepend space in file name with \

Comment: When you only pass 1 parameter to `exec`, it's supposed to be the path to the executable. Are you actually trying to execute your json file?

Comment: no, I try to export there path and then open it

Comment: Try runtime.exec(String.format("export $MY_FILEPATH='%s'", somePath));

Comment: This also doesn't work: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: On which OS are you running this?

Comment: @jingx: a single `String` to `ProcessBuilder` is the program name, which can be a full path but doesn't need to if it is on (envvar) PATH, but a single `String` to `Runtime.exec` can be multiple whitespace-delimited tokens of which only the first is the program name, somewhat (but not entirely) like a typical command line to a shell (or Windows CMD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add: mostly dupe [Why does Runtime.exec(String) work for some but not all commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776546/why-does-runtime-execstring-work-for-some-but-not-all-commands)

**`Runtime.exec` is not a shell**

1. The overloads of `Runtime.exec` that take a `String` tokenize at whitespace. Period. A shell tokenizes at whitespace by default but this can be overridden with quotes or backslash; in `Runtime.exec` it cannot. If you want any other tokenization you have to use the overloads that take `String[]` instead. This answers the question you actually asked. For example you could do the equivalent of `open 'path with spaces'` by:

```java
Process p = runtime.exec (new String[] {"open", "path with spaces"});
```

2. `Runtime.exec` runs programs only. Shell commands *often* run a program but not always. `export` is a shell builtin that the shell executes but is not a program so `Runtime.exec` cannot.
3. `Runtime.exec` runs programs in child processes, which *is* like a shell. Even if you could somehow run `export` as a child process, the change it makes would exist *only* in that child process. It would NOT affect the Java process or any other programs run from the Java process, just like if you use shell to do `export` in a child process -- most simply a subshell using parentheses like `( export foo=bar; echo $foo ); echo $foo` -- then it is set only in the child shell process and not the parent shell, and not any other children of the parent shell.

Thus if your goal is to set an environment variable *to be used by some other program(s)*, you cannot do that by running *anything* in `Runtime.exec`. You can pass an environment that is modified to add (or change or delete) environment variables to some other (real) program you run with `Runtime.exec` by using the overloads that take an `envp` parameter -- see [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) -- or with `ProcessBuilder` by using the `environment()` method [(javadoc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment--)

But if your goal is to do the equivalent of shell's `foo='path with spaces'; open "$foo"` (note quotes are needed for this to work in shell) you can't. The substitution of `$foo` to `path with spaces` (within a token, and thus passed as an argument) is done *by the shell* not by the `open` program -- and `Runtime.exec` is not a shell so it doesn't do this. You have to pass the `path with spaces` token/argument yourself as in point 1 above, or explicitly run a shell (commonly `/bin/sh` or just `sh`) and give *the shell* the `foo=...; ...$foo...` commands to execute -- and `export` isn't needed since the variable is used only in the shell not the child process.

BTW even in shell you don't use a `$` when you *set* an environment variable or shell variable, only when you *use* the value of a variable (or of certain other things like a command substitution or arithmetic expression).