# Command working in terminal, but "no closing quote" error when used Process.exec

Tags: java, linux

I have the following method inside a Java program

```
public static void enableAirplaneMode() {
    String s = null;
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = null;
        String command = "adb shell \"su -c 'settings put global airplane_mode_on 1'\"";
        System.out.println(command);
        pr = rt.exec(command);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        pr.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output of the above method is

```
adb shell "su -c 'settings put global airplane_mode_on 1'"
/system/bin/sh: no closing quote
```

But if I copy/paste the command in terminal directly everything works as expected. Why am I getting the "no closing quote" error here?

Comment: try [passing an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) `String[] command = {"adb", "shell", "su -c 'settings put global airplane_mode_on 1'"};`.

Comment: That works, you may post it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776546/why-does-runtime-execstring-work-for-some-but-not-all-commands and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425729/whitespace-in-bash-path-with-java and probably more I can't find quickly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try [passing an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) as suggested on javadocs.

```
String[] command = {"adb", "shell", "su -c 'settings put global airplane_mode_on 1'"};
```