# use javap from within a java program on all the files

Tags: java, javap

I have to implement javap -verbose from within a java program, the directory named folder has multiple classes and i want to use this javap -verbose on all of them so i do,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javap -verbose folder/*");
```

in my java program but it does not work(Program compiles and runs but no output is obtained), However when i do

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javap -verbose folder/java_1.class");
```

it runs(and output is obtained).
Also if I do

```
javap -verbose folder/*
```

on the command line it works.
I am using latest version of Ubuntu. How can i apply javap on all the files of a directory. 
Note: folder has no sub-directory.

Comment: it seems you need to recurse all the files to be passed to `javap`

Comment: @BagusTesa how can I do that, and why is it that using * works in command line but not from within java file

Comment: You have to implement this why? Very strange requirement.

Comment: It works well on my environment.

Comment: @EJP I have to write a java program to analyze the number of constant pool in the classes (from n classes kept in a directory)

Comment: @saka1029  it runs on mine as well but no output is generated, the program runs and then just ends, I used inputstream to catch the output and the output is nothing.

Comment: Mostly dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776546/why-does-runtime-execstring-work-for-some-but-not-all-commands -- `Runtime.exec` is not a shell, so you must either run a shell to expand the pattern (and then execute javap), or expand the pattern yourself. (PS: this actually works only if 'folder' is actually a package of classes. Java _sometimes_ uses directory=folder structure for package structure, but there are lots of directories or folders which aren't packages, and lots of files that aren't classes, and this won't work in those cases.)