# Android: How to process output of Runtime.getRuntime().exec() calling dumpsys on rooted phone

Tags: android, kotlin, exec, rooted-device, dumpsys

I am working on a small proof of concept on a rooted phone, which relys on being able to read `dumpsys` output.

If I call dumpsys on my (rooted) phone running Android 11 like this, using adb:

```
adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep "mCi="
```

I get a pretty long printout. The `grep` filters for lines containing cell tower IDs, but that shouldn't e important here (it's just an example). Now I'm trying to execute the same command inside a very simple app, and log its output, like this:

```
private  fun test() {
       
        try {
            val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su dumpsys telephony.registry | grep \"mCi=\"")
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
            val string = bufferedReader.readText()
            Timber.d("output: $string")
            bufferedReader.close() // do I need this?
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // handle Exception
        }
    }
```

I get no output at all (`string` length is 0). If I replace my process command with something simple like this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo 'abcde'")` the output is logged as intended (`output: 'abcde'`).

I also tried shortening the possible output, in case that was the problem by appending `--max-count=1`, to have grep only put out the first found line. Again, it works using adb, does not work in code.

what am I doing wrong?

(I am using [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) to print my logs, if anyone doesn't know what that line is in the xample.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to log the `stderr` stream that is available for your process as well. This will give you information about what is wrong with your command.

Your command is not correctly processed as it is seen as one command. The reason is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31776547/7947994).

The solution is to use a `String[]` as an argument of `exec` and explicitly execute the command with the shell. I wrote some code that executes your command, but it is in Java on an unrooted device. Still, it generates output and grep works.

```java
String[] arrayCommand = {"sh", "-c","dumpsys telephony.registry | grep \"permission\""};
            
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = r.exec(arrayCommand);

String stdoutString = convertInputStreamToString(process.getInputStream());
String stderrString = convertInputStreamToString(process.getErrorStream());
```

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, as it put me on the right track, but it is not complete when running from Kotlin, as I found. Here is my version of the arrayCommand: `val arrayCommand = arrayOf("su", "-c", "dumpsys", "telephony.registry", "|", "grep", "\"mCi=\"")`. I had to add a new string to my array after every space.
Also, running dumpsys without root or being a System app should only work on extremely old OS versions, so I needed that in (running Android 11).

Comment: If you dont mind can you post your complete code? Or  ```bufferedReader.close()``` needed?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the perfect way of doing it. For sure you should wrap the `InputStream` with some BufferedReader (see [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process#getInputStream())). Also, these readers implement the `AutoCloseable` interface, which means you can conveniently create them within the [`try-with-resource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement and closing the streams will be handled automatically. In the `catch` clause you can then capture any exceptions that could occur.